# Loop SQL Insert from C# Array

Tags: c#, sql

I have an array that holds a product id and the quantity, acting as a shopping basket.

My present loop allows me to insert the data into my table when the array count is 1:

```
var p = Basket.arrayList;

    for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
        // Loop through List 
    {
        var ProductId = p[i][0];
        var Quantity = p[i][1];
        itemsQueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tOrderItems (orderId, name, quantity) VALUES (@OrderId, @name, @quantity )";
        itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", id);
        itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ProductId);
        itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Quantity);

        itemsQueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

If the array holds any more than 1 it throws an error saying; "The variable name '@OrderId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

I really don't know how to fix this... Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispose` your command with `using` statement on each iteration and create a new one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
{
    var ProductId = p[i][0];
    var Quantity = p[i][1];
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection; // <-- don't forget to set connection
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tOrderItems (orderId, name, quantity) VALUES (@OrderId, @name, @quantity )";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ProductId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Quantity);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is my best bet, I've tried with your code but it errors on cmd.itemsQueryCommand ( so i changed it to var 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ProductId); and added cmd.dispose(); now it errors with - Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: @Matastic sorry it's my mistake :) I have noticed that and updated my answer.Set your connection property and it should be fine

Comment: You've nailed it, Thank You Very Much :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var p = Basket.arrayList;

itemsQueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tOrderItems (orderId, name, quantity) VALUES (@OrderId, @name, @quantity )";
itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrderId");
itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@name");
itemsQueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@quantity");


for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
    // Loop through List 
{
    itemsQueryCommand.Parameters["@OrderId"] = id;
    itemsQueryCommand.Parameters["@name"] =  p[i][0]; // ProductId;
    itemsQueryCommand.Parameters["@quantity"] = p[i][1]; //Quantity;

    itemsQueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I suggest to change the Add with AddWithValue using a dummy value of the correct datatype.

Comment: @Steve - The best way is to change the parameter to Add() to a new Parameter object.

Comment: Well, too late now, but I was talking about that this form of Add is not valid. Passing a string doesn't work. It throws an InvalidCastException. It is a pity because the idea is right. The parameter collection doesn't change inside the loop so there is no point to rebuild the whole thing at every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers and your error suggests, you're reusing a parameter value (so your  '@OrderId' is added more than once).

Either create a new command everytime (serman22 solution), or reuse the command value only (like hogan suggested).

In either case, I'd suggest you do some reading about the sql commands and C#, to refresh them in your mind.

Comment: Agreed - But I've only been programming for 8 weeks. Thanks :)

Comment: that's a start ... keep doing it if you enjoy it, and in no time (well, some time), it'll all come together :)